# What's the best way to include predefined constant table data in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Developing a small WPF Windows Client application in C#, Visual Studio.

It needs a whole lot of constant tabular data, and I'm interested whether it's best to put it in a local database, or load it from a text file, or some other solution?

Note that the data itself is complete and sealed, not needing ever to be edited after compiling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLite](http://sqlite.org/) is often used to store data of this nature especially if the data fits well into the paradigm of relational databases or if you have complex requirements for extraction in which SQL queries work best. There is a native .NET data provider for SQLite [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/).

Answer (score 2):

You can always put it in a resource.

Answer (score 1):

you already have the answer where to store you data. as for file format... my vote goes to `XML`